# Apply the ratio test to prove the serieis converges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Theres not answer in the back of the book to check my work against

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}=\frac{1}{k!}$$

Applying the ratio test: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{k+1!}}{\frac{1}{k!}}$$

which simplifies to:

$$\frac{k}{k+1!}=\frac{1}{k+1}$$

taking the limit: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} = \frac{1}{\infty + 1}= \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

Comment: Your computations are correct and you can deduce from them that your series converges.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The result is correct of course but there are some typos.

Comment: We need to consider $\frac{\frac{1}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{1}{k!}}$ and not $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{k+1!}}{\frac{1}{k}}$ which simplifies to $\frac{k!}{k+1!}=\frac{1}{k+1}$  and not $\frac{k}{k+1!}=\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: @user You are right, of course. I missed those typos.

Comment: Yes I think I corrected the typos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct but there is some typo, we have indeed

$$ \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\frac{\frac{1}{(k+1)!}}{\frac{1}{k!}}=\frac{k!}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1}{k+1} \to 0$$

as an alternative, since eventually $k!\ge k^2$ as $k\ge 4$, by direct comparison test we have

$$\sum_{k=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!} \le \sum_{k=4}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}$$